# How can I process dataframe using for loop in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
### Part1 --------------------------------------------------------------
data5 <- data.frame(late_AMD_1st=c(1, NA, 3, 4), RVO_1st=c(5, 6, NA, 8))
# late_AMD_1st RVO_1st
# 1            1       5
# 2           NA       6
# 3            3      NA
# 4            4       8
data5 <- subset(data5, !(is.na(data5$late_AMD_1st)))
data5 <- subset(data5, !(is.na(data5$RVO_1st)))
# data5
# late_AMD_1st RVO_1st
# 1            1       5
# 4            4       8
```

```
### Part2 --------------------------------------------------------------

data5 <- data.frame(late_AMD_1st=c(1, NA, 3, 4), RVO_1st=c(5, 6, NA, 8))
col_name <- c("late_AMD_1st", "RVO_1st")
for (i in col_name){
  data5 <- subset(data5, !(is.na(data5$i)))
}
# data5
# [1] late_AMD_1st RVO_1st     
# <0 行> (または長さ 0 の row.names)
```

I want to do the same thing as Part1 in Part2. But somehow I get the different data.frame in Part2. Am I wrong in using for loops?

Comment: You can do this without a loop as well with `na.omit(data5)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a loop

```
data5 <- data.frame(late_AMD_1st=c(1, NA, 3, 4), RVO_1st=c(5, 6, NA, 8))
col_name <- c("late_AMD_1st", "RVO_1st")
for (i in col_name){
  data5 <- subset(data5, !(is.na(data5[, i])))
}

data5
#late_AMD_1st RVO_1st
#1            1       5
#4            4       8
```

Here, `data5[, i]` is the column name in `i` of `data5`.

---

You can do this without a loop much easily if your aim is to remove *all* the rows with `NA`s.

```
na.omit(data5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I want to remove only rows with ```NA```s in specific columns. So I would rather use ```data5[, i]```.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the approach `na.omit(data5)` by [@Suren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797422/12158757), you can also use the following code, which applies to data frames with more columns

```
res <- subset(data5,complete.cases(data5))
```

or

```
res <- subset(data5,Reduce(`&`,data.frame(!is.na(data5))))
```

such that

```
> res
  late_AMD_1st RVO_1st
1            1       5
4            4       8
```